# c# method with List / param int[] parameters

Tags: c#

I have to make method called CalculateBill with given parameters, but I cannot define how to connect those two parameters inside of code.

```
public class Bill {

    public int CalculateBill (List<Item> itemList, params int[] items) {

// Need to write code here
//itemList : available items in the shop
// int[] items : array of ItemId's purchased by customer 
// A customer can buy same item many times , so itemId can be repeated in items array 
// return sum of al items prices 

    }
}
```

The item class is like

```
public class Item {
    public int ItemId {get; set;}
    public int ItemPrice { get; set; }

}
```

The Program Class is like

```
            List<Item> itemList = new List<Item> {
                new Item() {ItemId = 100 , ItemPrice = 50},
                new Item() {ItemId = 101 , ItemPrice = 60},
                new Item() {ItemId = 102 , ItemPrice = 20},
            };

            Bill bObj = new Bill();
           int a = bObj.CalculateBill(itemList, 101, 102, 101);
            int b = bObj.CalculateBill(itemList);
```

Comment: Make `ItemPrice` a `decimal` type for clarity.

Comment: What purpose does the `int[] items` serve?  The data is part of the vaguely named `Item` class and seems redundant. Also, might not `Item` need a quantity? Aside from that, what is the problem and what is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need help implementing the CalculateBill function using your existing architecture. I would implement it like below.

I renamed your 'itemList' parameter to 'itemsInShop' and I also renamed your 'items' parameter to 'itemsPurchasedIDs'. Always try to make your variable names as descriptive as possible to make it easy to understand and read.

```
public int CalculateBill(List<Item> itemsInShop, params int[] itemsPurchasedIDs)
{

    int totalSpent = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < itemsPurchasedIDs.Length; i++)
    {
        int itemId = itemsPurchasedIDs[i];

        for (int j = 0; j < itemsInShop.Count; j++)
        {
            var shopItem = itemsInShop[j];

            if (shopItem.ItemId == itemId)
            {
                totalSpent += shopItem.ItemPrice;
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    return totalSpent;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Create a class for the shop that contains the items available so you don't need to pass it as an argument.

Also, since you want to retrieve `Item`s with id values, you need a `Dictionary<int,Item>` which would allow you to do this quickly.

Here is the `Shop` class with a dictionary

```
public class Shop
{
    private readonly Dictionary<int, Item> _items;

    public Shop()
    {
        _items = new Dictionary<int, Item>();
    }

    public IReadOnlyList<Item> Items { get => _items.Values.ToList();  }
    public void Add(Item item) => _items.Add(item.ItemId, item);

    public Item[] GetItems(params int[] idList)
    {
        List<Item> list = new List<Item>();
        foreach (var id in idList)
        {
            list.Add(_items[id]);
        }
        return list.ToArray();
    }

    public decimal CalculateBill(params int[] idList)
    {
        var items = GetItems(idList);
        decimal sum = 0m;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            sum += item.ItemPrice;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you would need to lookup the items one by one. Here is a solution that uses  the`List.Find()` method to match the `Item` from the `id`.

```
public class Shop
{
    private readonly List<Item> _items;

    public Shop()
    {
        _items = new List<Item>();
    }

    public IReadOnlyList<Item> Items { get => _items.ToList();  }
    public void Add(Item item) => _items.Add(item);

    public Item[] GetItems(params int[] idList)
    {
        List<Item> list = new List<Item>();
        foreach (var id in idList)
        {
            list.Add(_items.Find((item)=>item.ItemId==id));
        }
        return list.ToArray();
    }

    public decimal CalculateBill(params int[] idList)
    {
        var items = GetItems(idList);
        decimal sum = 0m;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            sum += item.ItemPrice;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are three alternatives for you to try:

```
public int CalculateBill(List<Item> itemsInShop, params int[] itemsPurchasedIDs) =>
    itemsPurchasedIDs
        .Join(itemsInShop, id => id, item => item.ItemId, (_, item) => item.ItemPrice)
        .Sum();

public int CalculateBill2(List<Item> itemsInShop, params int[] itemsPurchasedIDs) =>
(
    from id in itemsPurchasedIDs
    join item in itemsInShop on id equals item.ItemId
    select item.ItemPrice
).Sum();

public int CalculateBill3(List<Item> itemsInShop, params int[] itemsPurchasedIDs)
{
    var map = itemsInShop.ToDictionary(x => x.ItemId, x => x.ItemPrice);
    return itemsPurchasedIDs.Sum(x => map[x]);
}
```